# Array changes value from string to number

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to assign a hex color value to an array. This is not possible, because when I assign the value, it is changed to a number. Here is the code that does that:

```
settings := {myColor: "color"}

myColor := "color"

settingName := "myColor"
settingValue := "0x00FF00"


%settingName% := settingValue
settings[settingName] := settingValue

e := settings[settingName]
MsgBox %e% - %settingValue%
;Displays 65280 - 0x00FF00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you went wrong in the 5th code line. Variables that you define do not get % signs.

```
settings := {myColor: "color"}
myColor := "color"

settingName := "myColor"
settingValue := "0x00FF00"

settingName = %settingValue% ; Alternative 1
settingName := settingValue ; Alternative 2
settings[settingName] := settingValue
e := settings[settingName]
MsgBox % e " -  " settings[settingName] " - " settingValue
;Displays  0x00FF00 - 0x00FF00 - 0x00FF00
ExitApp
```

Though I think that you want: Settings[MyColor] = 0x00FF00, you now have Settings[0x00FF00] = 0x00FF00.

```
settings := {myColor: "color"}
myColor := "color"

settingName := "myColor"
settingValue := "0x00FF00"
settings[settingName] := settingValue

MsgBox % settings[settingName] " - " settingValue
;Displays  0x00FF00 - 0x00FF00
ExitApp
```